# Dirichlet Inverses of Binomial Coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients, dirichlet-series, dirichlet-convolution

Let $\omega$ be a real number between $0$ and $1$, and let:

$$\mathbf{c}\left(n\right)=\binom{\omega+n-1}{n}$$

for all positive integers $n$. Is there a closed form for the Dirichlet inverse $\mathbf{c}^{-1}\left(n\right)$ of this function; i.e., for the function $\mathbf{c}^{-1}\left(n\right)$ so that the formal identity: $$\left(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbf{c}\left(m\right)}{m^{s}}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathbf{c}^{-1}\left(n\right)}{n^{s}}\right)=1$$ holds. If so, what is it?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying your intention about a binomial coefficient with non-integer entries?

Comment: I define the binomial coefficient using the Gamma function: $\binom{z}{w}=\frac{\Gamma\left(z+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(w+1\right)\Gamma\left(z-w+1\right)}$ for all complex numbers $z$ and $w$.

Comment: It might be useful to insert the Gamma-function convention into your question.

Comment: Actually $\Gamma$ is not required here: $c(n)=\omega(\omega+1)\cdots(\omega+n-1)/n!$